# Regular expression grep-parsing from 2 variables

Tags: r, regex, grepl

The purpose is to collapse/re-assign levels as part of cleaning a dataset.

Here is the example:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 <- c("cat","lion","cat","beast","cat"),
             V2 <- c("nice and grumpy","angry","old,but also nice","empty","has friends"),
             stringsAsFactors = F); colnames(df) <- c("V1","V2")
>df
     V1          V2
1   cat   nice and grumpy
2  lion             angry
3   cat   old,but also nice
4 beast             empty
5   cat       has friends
```

The level of interest is `cat`; these are the entries:

```
parse1 <- V1[grepl("cat",V1)]
#[1] "cat" "cat" "cat"
```

From there, the idea is to search for an attribute in `V2`, `nice`, upon which the level `cat` will be renamed as `nice cat`. This search locates 2 entries of interest in `V2`:

```
 df.sub <- subset(df,V1=="cat",select=V1:V2)
 parse2 <- df.sub$V2[grep("([Nn]ice)",df.sub$V2)]
#[1] "nice and grumpy"   "old,but also nice"
```

The ideal final result would have `df` transformed to:

```
     V1                V2
1   nice cat   nice and grumpy
2   lion           king
3   nice cat   old,but also nice
4   beast           empty
5   cat        has friends
```

Any thoughts how to achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: donno how king comes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ifelse` seems to be enough for this:

```
df$V1 <- ifelse(grepl("([Nn]ice)", df$V2), 
                sub('cat', 'nice cat', df$V1), 
                df$V1 )
```

Output:

```
> df
        V1                V2
1 nice cat   nice and grumpy
2     lion             angry
3 nice cat old,but also nice
4    beast             empty
5      cat       has friends
```

Comment: @ LyzandeR: Thanks so much!

Comment: You re welcome, glad I could be of help :). Just to be fair if you have a massive data.frame (more than 1m rows for example), `data.table` will certainly be much faster (this is why it was created). `data.table` has a slightly different syntax than normal data.frame operations which you will need to familiarise yourself with before you use. Make sure you use it in the right way though. In the other answer `paste0` and checking whether `V1=='cat'` seems superfluous and will slow down the code  (I assume your original data frame might be different).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data.table`

```
df <- data.frame(V1 <- c("cat","lion","cat","beast","cat"),
         V2 <- c("nice and grumpy","angry","old,but also nice","empty","has friends"),
         stringsAsFactors = F); colnames(df) <- c("V1","V2")

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
# All the nice animals
DT[grepl ("([Nn]ice)",V2), V3:= paste0("nice ",V1)]
# All the nice cats
DT[grepl ("([Nn]ice)",V2) & V1=="cat", V4:= paste0("nice ",V1)]
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have a slight preference for the other solution since dealing with huge dataframe.